# Installing bitcoin and bitcoincash on same server

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I have installed bitcoin core by using its source code in my amazon server by using the instructions given in the below youtube link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tG_24G7bj_w

> Some portion of the commands that i used to install the bitcoin from
>   the source code were given below,
>
> sudo mv ./include/bitcoinconsensus.h
>   /usr/local/include/bitcoinconsensus.h mkdir -p /usr/local/lib sudo mv
>   ./lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so /usr/local/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so
>   sudo mv ./lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0
>   /usr/local/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0 sudo mv
>   ./lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
>   /usr/local/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0 chmod 644
>   /usr/local/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0
>   /usr/local/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0

Its running fine in my server. Now I need to install bitcoincash also in the same server using the source file.
I got the source file of bitcoincash from the below link

https://www.bitcoinunlimited.info/download

But i have a doubt that is there any conflict will occure when we install two coins in the same server,

> also from the given commands we can see that we have to move some
>   common folders(eg libbitcoinconsensus.so , libbitcoinconsensus.so.0 )
>   to the /usr/local/lib/ fiolder and /usr/local/include/ folder for
>   installing both coin.

Then how can i install both coins from the source? Can alyone please give me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

install Bitcoin ABC on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, alongside Bitcoin Core, using these instructions:

*Note: You have to create a new username because bitcoin and bitcoin cash use the same directory, so it won't work.*

1. Download the appropriate binary from here: https://download.bitcoinabc.org/

   For me, the command would be:

   `wget https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.16.2/linux/bitcoin-abc-0.16.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`
2. Extract the archive:

   `tar xzvf bitcoin-abc-0.16.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`
3. Rename the binary files:

   `cd bitcoin-abc-0.16.2/bin/; rename 's/bitcoin/bitcoinCash/' *`
4. Install the files into `/usr/local/bin`:

   `sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin *`

Finally!

`bitcoinCashd -version` outputs:

> Bitcoin ABC Daemon version v0.16.2.0-6af5e93
>
> [...]

`bitcoind -version` outputs:

> Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.15.1
>
> [..]

`ls /usr/local/bin` outputs:

```
bitcoinCash-cli  bitcoinCash-seeder  bitcoind    test_bitcoin
bitcoinCashd     bitcoinCash-tx      bitcoin-qt  test_bitcoinCash
bitcoinCash-qt   bitcoin-cli         bitcoin-tx
```

*Note: You have to edit the default port on bitcoin.conf file, Since Bitcoin-core and Bitcoin-cash will use the same RPC port. `rpcport=4523`*

Comment: Thank you Adam for your reply.But I have a doubt does these two coins bitcoin abc and bitcoincash are same?

Comment: Finally I installed and run both wallets bitcoin and bitcoincash on same server.I just rename some executable files and connected both wallets on different ports.Thank you...

Comment: This will cause problems. Both the Bitcoin Core and ABC will try to use the port `8333`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The bitcoinCashd and bitcoind -version works, but when running it, the commands such as bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo and bitcoinCash-getinfo both return the first daemon run.  Both cant be run at once

Comment: I created user1 and user2 installed bitcoin and bitcoincash the same way.  I also try starting them pointing at the config file

Comment: are you starting them from each app user? I mean you have to start to call `BitcoinCash-cli getnetworkinfo` from `user2`

Answer (score 0):

**The necessary settings for bitcoin and bitcoincash to work on the same machine are as follows.
Examine all files well grasp the differences between them.**

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
mkdir bitcoin
cd /user

wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

tar -zxvf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

sudo install -m 0755 -o user -g user -t /usr/local/bin/bitcoin ~/bitcoin-0.20.0/bin/*

rm -rf ~/bitcoin-0.20.0/ bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz



cd /usr/local/bin/
mkdir bitcoincash
cd /user    

wget https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/releases/download/v0.22.3/bitcoin-abc-0.22.3-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

tar -zxvf bitcoin-abc-0.22.3-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

sudo install -m 0755 -o user -g user -t /usr/local/bin/bitcoincash ~/bitcoin-abc-0.22.3/bin/*

rm -rf ~/bitcoin-abc-0.22.3/ bitcoin-abc-0.22.3-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

cd /usr/local/bin/bitcoincash

mv bitcoin-cli bitcoincash-cli
mv bitcoind bitcoincashd
mv bitcoin-qt bitcoincash-qt
mv bitcoin-seeder bitcoincash-seeder
mv bitcoin-tx bitcoincash-tx
mv bitcoin-wallet bitcoincash-wallet
```

> Bitcoin Conf.

```
cd /user
mkdir .bitcoin
nano bitcoin.conf
```

copy and paste code.

```
regtest=1
server=1
txindex=1
daemon=1
debug=0
datadir=/user/bitcoin
rpcuser=hedehude
rpcpassword=hedehude
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/16
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
deprecatedrpc=accounts

[test]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/16
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332

[regtest]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/16
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:38332
```

> BitcoinCash Conf.

```
cd /user
mkdir .bitcoincash
nano bitcoincash.conf
```

copy and paste code.

```
regtest=1
server=1
txindex=1
daemon=1
debug=0
datadir=/user/bitcoincash
rpcuser=hedehude
rpcpassword=hedehude
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=78332
port=7870
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/16
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
deprecatedrpc=accounts

[test]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=78332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/16
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332

[regtest]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=78332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/16
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:88332
```

To run nodes...

> For Bitcoin Service

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
nano bitcoind.service
```

copy and paste code.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bitcoin Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=user
Type=forking
PIDFile=/user/bitcoin/bitcoind.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoin/bitcoind -pid=/user/bitcoin/bitcoind.pid -conf=/user/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -datadir=/user/bitcoin
KillMode=process
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=120
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> For BitcoinCash Service

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
nano bitcoincashd.service
```

copy and paste code.

```
[Unit]
Description=BitcoinCash Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=user
Type=forking
PIDFile=/user/bitcoincash/bitcoincashd.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoincash/bitcoincashd -pid=/user/bitcoincash/bitcoincashd.pid -conf=/user/.bitcoincash/bitcoincash.conf
KillMode=process
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=120
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run services

```
sudo systemctl start bitcoind.service
sudo systemctl status bitcoind.service
```

Status is success...

```
sudo systemctl enable bitcoind.service

sudo systemctl start bitcoincashd.service
sudo systemctl status bitcoincashd.service
```

Status is success...

```
sudo systemctl enable bitcoincashd.service
```

Now, when querying through the terminal,

For Bitcoin

```
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin/./bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
```

For BitcoinCash

```
/usr/local/bin/bitcoincash/./bitcoincash-cli -conf=/user/.bitcoincash/bitcoincash.conf getblockchaininfo
```

When querying rpc with curl,

For Bitcoin

```
curl -u hedehude:hedehude --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": []}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:28332/
```

For BitcoinCash

```
curl -u hedehude:hedehude --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": []}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:78332/
```

***It should be running smoothly now ...
Good luck.***