# How can I exactly use both the rpc API of Bitcoin and the rpc API of Bitcoin cash on the same server or machine?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cash

I've looked for an exactly answer but I really couldn't find it.
So can someone let me know the why of doing what I'm asking correctly?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have Bitcoin-core and bitcoin cash already installed alongside, follow my answer in [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70403/installing-bitcoin-and-bitcoincash-on-same-server) to install Bitcoin-cash alongside Bitcoin-core.

*It's so important creating a different username than bitcoin username because bitcoin and bitcoin cash use the same directory.*

Now login to Bitcoin username and edit this file `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

so it becomes like that:

```
rpcuser=myusername
rpcpassword=myRPCpa$$word
daemon=1
server=1
rpcport=5345
```

in here we are using different RPC port to bitcoin core. to know more about bitcoin config see [this website](https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/).

Now, do the same thing to Bitcoin-cash, and everything should work as it supposed to be.

if you have a firewall enabled, don't forget to allow chosen ports.

Comment: I use Mac OS can you show me an example for Mac OS as well?

Comment: And I saw there's a suspicion that both clients will try to use the same port, was this problem solved?

Comment: Yeah, we are using port 5345 for bitcoin-core and bitcoin cash will use port 8333 by default.
it doesn't really matter what are you using, just edit the config as above, and they should work alongside each other with no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change their data directory. Run one of them, either BTC or BCH, with `-datadir=C:/somewhere`. Then create `bitcoin.conf` in that folder. It should look like:

```
server=1
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=something
rpcport=8334
```

Make sure to set `rpcport` to something other than `8332` or `8333`. Also, add `port=something` to the `bitcoin.conf` of which node software that you like less.

Comment: Isn't there a doubt that both clients will try to use 8333 port and occur a problem?

Comment: @西田龍 That's why you should also add `port=BlahBlah` to one of them.

Comment: I've never seen the way of specifying port number on bitcoin.conf but it can be used normally, right?

Answer (score -2):

You can but u will need to run bitcoin and bitcoin cash server on a separate machine or same machine (if same machine, you will have to do little more config).

Answer (score -2):

You can, just run it with different port and each rpc will connect on each wallet port, the port could be configured in .conf file or as arg when you run bitcoin.exe